# Why is my / root directory labeled as file-type: "overlay"? loop-devs? (in the fdisk -l results::/dev/loop0 is squashFS--are they the "real" files?)

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, hard-drive

I hope the following is not over-kill on information! But I figured too much is better than not enough in this instance.

-----MY PERSONAL DISCLAIMER: I JUST STARTED LEARNING ANYTHING AT ALL ABOUT LINUX ABOUT 2-3 -----MONTHS AGO! PLEASE DON'T SHAME ME TOO BAD Y'ALL!!

SO, I have got my PC all kinds of screwed up (w/ the "help" of some sort of bad, malicious types who really don't want me to have a correctly functioning installation of ANY operating system, apparently, seeing as how they have also somehow blocked any recognition whatsoever by the UEFI-BIOS/smbios of NTFS installation files (Windows files of any kind actually!  major bummer guys... I'm so frustrated...).

Below is some of my terminal output from trying to chroot to my HDD (it IS an HDD and not an SSD so I don't understand how it got labeled as /sda.) There is also a nvme-256G with a broken U_22.04.1 installation on it that I want to just completely wipe out if possible and then, eventually, re-install Win11 as a multi-boot option.

***********(FROM MY BASH SHELL)*****************

ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ ls /mnt

EFI  grub

ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 2.13 GiB, 2288189440 bytes, 4469120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 61.96 MiB, 64970752 bytes, 126896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 163.29 MiB, 171225088 bytes, 334424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 400.8 MiB, 420265984 bytes, 820832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 45.86 MiB, 48091136 bytes, 93928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 284 KiB, 290816 bytes, 568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 882CC633-5457-41A0-AA12-6F1BE90F85D4

| Device         Start         End         Sectors       Size     Type                |
|:------------|:-----------:|:----------:|:-----------:|:-------:|-------------------:|
|/dev/sda1           2048          77823         75776       37M  MBR partition scheme|
|/dev/sda2        1050624     1758212095    1757161472    837.9G  Linux filesystem    |
|/dev/sda3          77824        1050623        972800      475M  Linux filesystem    |
|/dev/sda4     1758212096     1953523711     195311616     93.1G  Linux swap          |
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PM991a NVMe Samsung 256GB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A81813C3-774B-4F76-86C2-49ACE95BFBE0

| Device Start End Sectors Size Type |
| --- |
| /dev/nvme0n1p1 2048 1050623 1048576 512M EFI System |
| /dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 5244927 4194304 2G Linux swap |
| /dev/nvme0n1p3 5244928 9439231 4194304 2G Solaris boot |
| /dev/nvme0n1p4 9439232 500118158 490678927 234G Solaris root |

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.46 GiB, 15525216256 bytes, 30322688 sectors
Disk model: USB 2.0 FD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e127a

| Device         Start         End         Sectors       Size     Type                |

/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30322687 30320640 14.5G  b W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/loop8: 46.96 MiB, 49242112 bytes, 96176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt && for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done && sudo chroot /mnt && sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub && exit

mount: /mnt: /dev/sda1 already mounted on /mnt.

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type

/dev/sda1        2048      77823      75776    37M MBR partition scheme
/dev/sda2     1050624 1758212095 1757161472 837.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3       77824    1050623     972800   475M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  1758212096 1953523711  195311616  93.1G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: PM991a NVMe Samsung 256GB
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 16384 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: A81813C3-774B-4F76-86C2-49ACE95BFBE0

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type

/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624   5244927   4194304    2G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p3 5244928   9439231   4194304    2G Solaris boot
/dev/nvme0n1p4 9439232 500118158 490678927  234G Solaris root

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.46 GiB, 15525216256 bytes, 30322688 sectors
Disk model: USB 2.0 FD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e127a

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type

/dev/sdb1  *     2048 30322687 30320640 14.5G  b W95 FAT32

["Disks" screenshot of NVMe partitioning set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRaNj.png) ["Disks" screenshot of HDD
partitioning set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buOTn.png) ["Disks" screenshot of Jammy installation USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqV8e.png) [squashFS loop-device:/dev/loop0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuxDr.png) [/dev: details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTfyT.png) [/dev: details pg.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Mxw.png) [/dev: details pg.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEOq9.png) [more tty's,then:these "/dev"'s pg.4][9] [/dev: details pg.5][10] [following all the loop# the last of the /dev pg.6][11]

Comment: [9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUM5G.png
  [10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mer96.png

Comment: Only use gpt partitioning, not old MBR(msdos). Only boot in UEFI mode, to install in UEFI mode, both Windows & Ubuntu. You have large enough NVMe drive to have Windows & / (root) for Ubuntu and then have /home and/or data partitions (ext4 or NTFS) on HDD. If new user best to only use ext4, not the more advanced xfs or btrfs. If you want encryption you have to use LVM - logical volumes. Also more advanced. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi & https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu